# Работа с Cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Здравствуйте. Пишу небольшое приложение – справочник грибов. Есть 3  класса – 1 MainActivity с Listview , 2 класс -  Information – будет выводить информацию о грибах в зависимости от того на какой элемент ListView кликнул пользователь, информация о каждом грибе будет браться из БД,  3 класс  - работа с Базой данных SqLite.
Вот код моей Базы данных:

```
  public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {
        private SQLiteDatabase sqdb;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mushrooms.db";
        private  static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mushrooms_table";
        public static final String Mushroom1 = "mushroom1";
        public static final String Mushroom2 = "mushroom2";

        private static final String SQL_CREATE_ = "create table " + TABLE_NAME +" ("
                + DataBaseHelper._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + Mushroom1 + " text,"
                + Mushroom2 + " text" + ");";

        public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context , DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_);
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(Mushroom1 , "Білий гриб - один з найбільш цінних грибів. Росте в хвойних, " +
                        "листяних і змішаних лісах, звичайно на прогалинах і " +
                        "лісових узліссях, у рідкому молодому ялиннику, " +
                        "на вологому ґрунті з червня по жовтень. " +
                        "Забарвлення шляпки в дубових лісах темно-бура," +
                        " у листяних - світло-бура, у соснових - темно-бура з фіолетовим відтінком," +
                        " у ялинових - червонясто-бура. Нижня сторона капелюшка в молодих білих грибів біла, " +
                        "з віком жовтіє і нарешті стає жовтувато-зеленою.");

                 cv.put(Mushroom2 , "Існує кілька різновидів моховиків. " +
                         "Найбільш відомі жовто-бурий і зелений моховик. " +
                         "Жовто-бурий моховик росте в соснових лісах. " +
                         "Забарвлення сухого бархатистого капелюшка жовте чи жовтувато-буре. " +
                         "Зелений чи глухий моховик росте в хвойних і листяних лісах. " +
                         "Забарвлення бархатистого капелюшка жовтувато-зеленувате чи коричнювато - зеленувате. " +
                         "Нижня сторона капелюшка і м'якоть жовтуваті. М'якоть на зламі синіє. " +
                         "Моховики використовуються для готування других блюд (найкраще жарити) і маринування. " +
                         "При сушінні моховики чорніють.");

                 sqdb.insert(TABLE_NAME , null , cv);

                 db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            }finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }

        public String getInformation(int id) {
            sqdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String selection = "_id = ?";
            String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};
            Cursor  cursor = sqdb.query(TABLE_NAME , null , selection , selectionArgs , null , null, null);

    // работа с курсором
            sqdb.close();
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Так вот вопрос ,  видите я пишу метод  public String getInformation(int id), это метод будет вызываться во 2 классе - Information для того чтобы в зависиомсти от выбраного пункта бралась инфа из бд ,  с очередью я разобрался, теперь надо как то извлечь данные правильно?
будет ли правильно дописать в этод метод такой код:

```
 if(cursor != null) {
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
             String mush = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Mushroom1));
         }while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }
  }
  return mush;
```

Мне нужно чтобы в зависимости от id выводило информацию. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно тут использовать getColumnIndex.

Comment: А вообще заполнять таким образом базу данных не круто. Лучше подготовьте базу данных заранее с помощью например SqlLiteBrowser а потом готовую базу подключите в проект: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: а как мне по _id передавать готовую базу? я прочитал статью то что вы кинули, но что нужно добавить к тому коду чтобы оно выводило нужные мне данные в зависимости от выбраного элемента listview

Comment: Выводить так же как и сейчас, просто сейчас ты будешь изначально заполнять базу через insert описывая в коде весь текст, а если  у тебя там этих грибов разновидностей сотни - это же ад. Поэтому ты сразу берешь базу подготавливаешь отдельно, на компе, через sqlbrowser, заполняешь ее, а потом ложишь в assets файл с базой, при старте приложения, вместо create table и инсерт - подгружаешь готовую базу.

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin  скажите  вот базу я наполнил, тот код который подключает базу так его и писать? там ничего не нужно менять под мое условие?  Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно структуры базы данных, при запросе по полю "_id" будет выдана только одна запись, содержащая поля "_id", "Mushroom1" и "Mushroom2". 
Таким образом, функция getInformation(int id) в том варианте, в котором она сейчас написана, должна выводить только сведения из одного поля таблицы и иметь вид:

```
public String getInformation(int id) {
sqdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
String selection = "_id = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};
Cursor  cursor = sqdb.query(TABLE_NAME , null , selection , selectionArgs , null , null, null);
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){ // Проверка на наличие данных
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Mushroom1);
} else {
    return null;
}
cursor.close();
```

}

Для того, чтобы сразу получить все значения из строки таблицы стоит несколько изменить функцию:

```
public HashMap<String, Object> getInformation(final int id){
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    sqdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selection = "_id = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};
    Cursor  cursor = sqdb.query(TABLE_NAME , null , selection , selectionArgs , null , null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result.put("id", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
        result.put("Mushroom1", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Mushroom1");
        result.put("Mushroom2", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Mushroom2");
    }
    cursor.close();
    retrun result;
}
```

Comment: `cursor.moveToFirst()` вернет false, если `cursor` пустой, `if(cursor.getCount() > 0)` -  излишняя проверка, `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` проверит на наличие данных и перейдет к первой записи